# Remove duplicate list in jinja

Tags: python, html, jinja2

Im populating my html page using jinja, how can I remove duplication from output like using `set()` in python?

below is my code :

```
<label class="text-primary" for="search_type" style="display:inline-block;">Selected Status : </label>
{% for project_data in project_on_status_list %}
    <span>{{ project_data.get_project_stage_display }}, </span>
{% endfor %}
```

Output :

```
Selected Status :  In Progress, On Hold, On Hold, Completed,
```

Desired Output :

```
Selected Status :  In Progress, On Hold, Completed,
```

Comment: Yes. you can use set(list).

Comment: Hi @ManojJadhav, thansk for your reply can you show me how its done, I'm not sure how the syntax is, i tried is, but its not correct

Comment: ```s= ["In Progress", "On Hold", "On Hold", "Completed"]``` and set(s) you will get ```{'Completed', 'In Progress', 'On Hold'}``` or you can do list(set(s)) to get list as output ```['Completed', 'In Progress', 'On Hold']```

Comment: I have to write this inside view.py is it?

Comment: no you have to pass it to view

Comment: Did you try `{% for project_data in set(project_on_status_list) %}` ?

Comment: tried it produce an error, `Could not parse the remainder: '(project_on_status_list)' from 'set(project_on_status_list)'`

Comment: Can't you just pass the set to the render engine instead of trying to make a set out of a list inside the template itself?

Answer (score 3):

You need filter **unique**

```
`<label class="text-primary" for="search_type" style="display:inline-block;">
Selected Status : 
</label>
{% for project_data in project_on_status_list %}
<span>{{ project_data.get_project_stage_display | unique }}, </span>
{% endfor %}`
```

Comment: It shows the error `Invalid filter: 'unique'`

Comment: Which version of jinja are you using? I look in docs, from 2.0 this filter implemented.

Comment: I don't use any specific version. i use django 3.2. Does that makes any?